# TypeError: choose_category_button_clicked() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, initialization, typeerror

I am trying to get data from one py file and send it to another py file. Finally I use one last py file with a class in it as the main brain of the code. The code that I present you below is my main py file. I keep getting an error on the initialization of the QuizInterface.The error code is as follows:

> TypeError: choose_category_button_clicked() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Code:

```
import ui
from question_data_py import choose_category
from question_model import Question
from quiz_brain import QuizBrain
from ui import QuizInterface

quiz_ui = QuizInterface

chosen_category_main=QuizInterface.choose_category_button_clicked()
question_data=choose_category(chosen_category_main)
question_bank = []
def finalise_question_data(question_data):
    for question in question_data:
        question_text = question["question"]
        question_answer = question["correct_answer"]
        new_question = Question(question_text, question_answer)
        question_bank.append(new_question)
finalise_question_data(question_data)
quiz = QuizBrain(question_bank)

while quiz.still_has_questions():
    quiz.next_question()
```

i tried that adding parenthesis on the end of the class initialization. However I now get another error code:"TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quiz_brain'". The initialization of the quiz_brain class is on line 19

Comment: I think you should add `()` to `QuizInterface`

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
chosen_category_main=QuizInterface.choose_category_button_clicked()
```

to

```
chosen_category_main=QuizInterface().choose_category_button_clicked()
```

Becouse **choose_category_button_clicked()** method is not a classmethod or a staticmethod and you must call it from object instead of class

Comment: i tried that already. I get another error code:"TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quiz_brain'". The initialization  of the quiz_brain class is on line 19